# c:\Ruby187\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby

I have been running my `Ruby` program using the `Git Bash` console for a while now.

Lately, when I wanted to run a simple ruby program, i go the following on the console:

`c:\Ruby187\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory`

Why is that? And, how can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PATH environment variable under both User and System.

Looks like it sees where it should be. Potentially a permissions issue? Can you run with a regular command prompt? Start->run, cmd.exe, ruby -v?

Comment: Yes, for example when I run `ruby -v`, I get: `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]`

Comment: Then, you are clearly finding ruby.exe. I think this is a problem with Git bash.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had to explicitly save my ruby program with the extension `.rb` added at the end of the file name for this problem to disappear.

Thanks.